# how to use Auth0 with typescript-express-decorators

Tags: typescript, express, decorator, middleware, auth0

I am using the [typescript-express-decorators (ts.ed)](https://tsed.io/) library to build my restful apis. I would like to integrate it with a [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) authentication workflow. But I have no idea how to proceed. On the ts.ed pages, there is an example of how to setup authentication using [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) and middlewares.

The [Getting started with Node.js](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs) of Auth0 shows that I should build an express middleware (`express-jwt`) which checks for valid user access token included in the request. Then I should add this middleware to every secured route.

Here is a screenshot of such a setup (from "Getting Started" section):

[image]

So I guess my question is: how do I create a custom middleware and attach it to every route I would like to secure?

As I said, I looked at the documentation of ts.ed. And there is only an example with passport.js (using middleware and authenticated decorator).

I hope the ts.ed would see this question and give some guidance.

Comment: Hi. dId you solve the issue. I wrote my custom decorators and other middlewares work but i have issue with express-jwt library

Comment: Hello, I've moved to graphql since and no longer use the "ts.ed" library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use any middleware with `@Use` decorator. For example:

```
import { Controller, Use, Get, Req, Res, Next } from '@tsed/common'
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import permitAuth from '../middlewares/permitAuth'

@Controller('/account')
export default class AccountController {
    @Get('/userInfo')
    @Use(permitAuth())
    async userInfoGet(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response, @Next() next: NextFunction) {
        return res.json(req.user.toJSON())
    }
}
```

Also you may use it on controller level too:

```
@Controller('/my-controller')
@Use(myMiddleware)
export default class MyController {
    ...
}
```

Look http://tsed.io/docs/controllers.html#custom-middleware